# Performance of a Do-Loop of variable length

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

If I'm changing a basis depending on a (non quadratic) matrix $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbb Z^{d\times k}$ and some $\mu\in\mathbb N^k$, i.e. i have an array `a` of the same dimensions as mentioned in $\mu$, that is also given as an input parameter and I want to adress another array `b` at the same time after multiplication with $\mathbf{M}$. Hence i do need some `Do`-loop to run through all values $t = (t_1,\ldots,t_k),\ 1\leq t_i \leq \mu_i$.

Let's say `d=3; k=2; mM = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};` and `mu={512,1024}`

Then my approach (that works) is something like

```
a = ConstantArray[0, mu]; (* Given as input for the function usually*)
b = ConstantArray[0, mM.mu]; (*to be computed/ "filled" with values *)
t1 = AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[
    b[[Sequence @@ ( mM.Table[Subscript[t, j], {j, 1, k}])]]
      = a[[Sequence @@ (Table[Subscript[t, j], {j, 1, k}]) ]];
  ,Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{Subscript[t, j], 1, mu[[j]]}, {j, 1, k}]]];
]
```

Where the arrays in reality are of course not only zeros, usually they're not even sparse and i'm doing some computation not only the matching.

But even for this (i think) relatively small input  the time needed for evaluation is very long (65 seconds on my Core2Duo 2.4 Ghz / 8GB Ram / Mathematica 8.1), e.g. compared to a multivariate Fourier transform on `a` (which i do before that in less than a second).

This one gets even worse, if $\mathbf{M}$ “spreads“ `a`further, but that might also be due to Memory, perhaps.

In order to get that faster, I tried to extract the `Table` to be an Argument of an anonymous function (`# & [...]`), but that didn't gain any measurable time. Timing gets even worse, if i'm switching to my real application due to multiple access on the array `a` inside of `Do`.

What I am searching for now is a time optimization of that `Do` loop, whose Range is kind of variable with respect to the input $\mu$ and any ideas on faster access on `a` and `b`.

Comment: without further reading into your problem as i can't test anything right now anyway, maybe you can adjust your problem to use `NestWhile` or `NestWhileList`. i'm pretty confident that they are significantly faster than `Do`.

Comment: I tried to simplify the problem given here, in my application the right hand side is a Computation (certain sum of elements from `a`, but all “array index adresses” of course involve the actual one (written as the `Sequence@@Table` stuff. Thanks for the hint, I'll take a look at `NestWhile`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried adjusting the problem, bu i can't see how to do that - maybe i'm thinking too much in these Nested `Do` loops, but you're suggesting to replace `Do` kind of with `NestWhile` and i can't see how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting this up to use `ReplacePart` seems much faster than replacing parts in a loop. The function `f` here creates a list of replacement rules and then performs the replacement. The uses of `Thread` are there to appropriately expand out the rules and lists.

Note that this is pretty memory intensive. You won't be able to go much larger than your sample problem without exhausting your memory at 8GB.

```
f[a_, b_, mM_] :=
 Block[{t, mu, k, d, elem, index, rng, rep},
  mu = Dimensions[a];
  k = Length[mu];
  d = Length[mM];
  elem = mM.Table[t[j], {j, 1, k}];
  rng = Sequence @@ Table[{t[j], 1, mu[[j]]}, {j, 1, k}];
  index = Partition[Flatten[Table @@ {elem, rng}], d];
  rep = Thread[index -> Flatten[a]];
  ReplacePart[b, rep]
  ]

f[a, b, mM]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{4.680007, Null}*)
```

Comment: Uff, looks nice, but I don't understand Lines 3 and 4. Absolutely nothing. Can you explain them a little bit more? so `{t1, t2}` is my $\mu$ (because as input it doesn't matter whether you know `a` or $\mu$) but i can't recognize for example my “transformation rule” encoded in $\mathbf{M}$.

Comment: Well from `Print[index]` even for very small examples, i can't recognize the $\mathbf{M}$ or any useful structure to work with (and feel a little dumb if you mention “immediately”) - I'm sorry. The matrix should also be a variable of the function, that's why. I'll take a closer look on Partition an MapThread, though, just running your code with the numbers i posted as an example, it takes (on my humble machine, see above) your 4 seconds (while mine is at 18, maybe something messed up the timing this morning).

Comment: Ouh, we missunderstood each other, _my_ implementation from above takes 18 seconds, while your code reproduces the 4 seconds exactly as you mentioned also on my machine.

Comment: Okay, I think I got your idea, but i think to implement that for other values of $k,d$ (or even have them variable too) might be a challenge.

Comment: I've added a more general solution.

Comment: That's at least far more readable. It's a little late (here), so i don't have Mathematica at hand. But i it reads quite nice. I'll try that tomorrow (also with my not mentioned further stuff to do on `a` and `b`), but I think your more general solution looks really nice and is the kind i looked for.

Comment: So, I did some tests and your code works really fine and I think i will accept it as the answer after some further tests. The only thing making me curious is, that the rules that are finally stored in `rep` have a quite heavy structure (of course, they are all multiplications with $\mathbf M$), so: Is there any chance to use a pattern for that? I couldn't adapt the pattern description in the Documentation of `ReplacePart`.

Comment: Probably, but I suspect that doing so is going to be slower than computing them up front (though perhaps less memory intensive). Keep in mind that they aren't persistent since they are defined in a `Block` so sometime after the `Block` exits they are cleaned up by the garbage collector.